# float: right reverses the order of the items

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I right align the last four li-items without changing something in the html (e.g. adding an ul, an id or a class)?

```css
ul li,
ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
    float: left;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't your code already do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display: flex` on the `<ul>` and define the margin of the 4th element as `auto`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li,
ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
</ul>
```